# "Pop-ups" blocked when Ctrl+Clicking

Tags: bug, user-interface, google-chrome

Sometimes when Ctrl+Clicking there's a "Pop-ups blocked" icon displayed instead of opening the new tab. Trying again immediately normally works.

It's probably a Chrome bug (because I think I've noticed it on other sites), but it definitely happens somewhat regularly on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: What exactly you try to click? Ordinary links e.g. question titles should always work, but it might get weird if you try to CTRL click something which only operates with JS, e.g. "flag".

Comment: I'm referring to question/answer links, mostly in Related or Linked lists, but also in search results and "Questions that may already have your answer", the latter happening as I entered this question.

Comment: Weird, never happened to me. Try with clean browser, without any userscripts/addons that might cause weird things to happen.

Comment: I will attempt that at some stage, and Grammarly does definitely affect this site, but I would not expect it to affect it this way (and I think I've noticed this issue from before Grammarly was around). No other extension obviously makes sense to affect the site in this way.

Comment: Just an update: because of Chrome's dislike of dynamic disks I have a clean browser to use (on WinXP), It has not yet happened there (I spent a couple of evenings catching up on Skeptics.SE), while it has happened again on this laptop (Win7). [I immediately loaded the same page on WinXP, but it worked fine, as did reclicking on Win7.] I have another desktop (Win8.1) where I think I remember it happening, but I'm not sure -- it definitely hasn't happened recently. I also have not yet had it happen to non-SE sites since I reported it :-(

Comment: So, still no idea what might be  causing it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, it is rare enough and not deterministically repeatable, so no idea yet. (I do still feel it is a Chrome bug except that I open new tabs when exploring Wikipedia as much as I do the SE sites and I don't recall it happening there. Unfortunately I don't specifically recall what "other sites" where I think I noticed the problem as well.)

Comment: My local newspaper's website did this _every_ the time for some links that were going to premium content, where right-clicking and choosing Open in a New Tab _does_ work, so that may have been one of my "other sites" (but they were likely really attempting to pop-up something). (Still hasn't happened on the clean Chrome install.)